# Use the size of a model in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am looking for a way to access the number of elements that are to be found in a model in QML.

For example:

```
Item {
    id: root
    Row {
        id: row
        height: root.height
        width: root.width
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            id: rep
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            model: [5, 3, 3, 1, 12]
            delegate: myDelegate
            Text {
                id: myDelegate
                text: "Element " + index + " of " size + ":" + modelData
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to retrieve the size of the model.
In the documentation I can find a property called `count`, but no hint how to access it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the model you're using. In your case, the model is a plain old JavaScript array, so you'd use `model.length`. Every other Qt type related to models or views has a count property: `ListModel`, `Repeater`, `ListView`, etc. So, you could also use `rep.count`, in your case.

Comment: Thank you! rep.count works like a charm. I will try the other at once!

Answer (score 1):

Generic way is to request repeater for it's underlying model count - in your case it would be `rep.count`.